# How to backup & restore the full system

Tags: dual-boot, backup, restore

I use a dual-boot with windows and Ubuntu

Every topic I've read says I "will need to unmount the drive I want to back up"

Is there any way to back up the system with apps I installed and everything from LiveCD or Windows? If yes how? How do I restore it?

I want to back up the system on the same Drive . I mean I have a C:, D:, F: (the partition I want to recover Ubuntu on) and the Sys, Swap partitions

I hate having to install apps, theme, servers every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the current stable version of Clonezilla (the iso file), and create a USB boot drive or CD boot disk. Boot from it and let Clonezilla do the job for you.

I suggest that you run at beginner level (I do that too after a few years). Make a compressed image of the whole drive. The image is a directory with a number of files, and Clonezilla can restore the system into the same drive or a new drive of at least the same size.

See this link: [clonezilla.org](http://clonezilla.org/)

-o-

Please notice that you should **backup to another drive**, either connected via the network in another computer or via USB or eSATA in the same computer.

Comment: can I backup on same hardDrive with but in different partition ?

Comment: You can do it, but it will not be a complete backup - so it will be complicated to restore compared to a complete backup of the whole drive. And - what would you do, when the drive is damaged physically?

Comment: but ? but what ?

Comment: It is much better to have the backup in a separate drive. The best is to keep it in a separate house, to keep the data safe against theft and fire etc. But at least, you should keep the backup in a separate drive, that is not connected to the computer all the time.

Comment: I think this's last question before accept this answer .
Can I backup on USB flash-drive ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but a USB flash drive is not as reliable as a USB hard disk drive.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck :-)